# Specifying a Service from an aar in Android Studio Manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-manifest

When attempting to set up a remote service in my application's manifest file, the

<service android:name="com.domain.package.service.Component" is reporting:

"Class referenced in the manifest, com.domain.package.service.Component, was not found in the project or the libraries"

What does AS use to resolve those in a manifest file?

Comment: It's looking in your app code and any libraries that you have added via Gradle. Are you sure that you have the fully-qualified class name correct?

Comment: Please share the ss of your android project structure so that we can assist you better.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's the odd part.  I am including the arr in the gradle, yet in the manifest that line is still "RED".  implementation(name: 'MyService', ext: 'aar'). In the past we didn't even have a <service> entry in our external app.  Thought that with API 28+ we now need it because I get "service not bound" when I run the app, so looking back at the manifest trying to add the <service> entry to see if that would bind the external service

Comment: To further complicate matter, this works on an Emulator even with the RED in the manifest, however on a real device, the service does not bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:  So taking a step back.  It turns out that the core reason we could not get to the service of the external app is that in Android11 we now need to add

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.domain.app" />
</queries>
```

to the app manifest.  It had nothing to do with adding the  to the app.